# PCIe hotplug hardware schematics reference design

Tags: pcie, hot-plug

I was going through this link, this was very wonderful

[Does PCIe hotplug actually work in practice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208767/does-pcie-hotplug-actually-work-in-practice?newreg=79e7de25474e40089491375752397905)

Following the above link, I had a question below:

1. I am looking for a "PCIe hotplug hardware schematics reference design" as per **PCI-sg standards**, could anyone please share me any example designs, like how does it looks like please?
2. Could any one please explain , why "PCIe PRSNT# signal connection" is needed, I am using BIOS & Linux environment, somehow I found this example link - https://blog.mbedded.ninja/electronics/communication-protocols/pci-express-pcie/pcie-hardware-design-guide/ -> it's not clear
3. mainly I want to understand, is there any hardware specific signals that signifies HotAdd & hotRemove, as per standard PCIe hotplug specifications?
4. Is that mandatory to introduce - a PCI hotplug controller IC or separate hardware IC chip , as PCI standards please?

Comment: As a representative of my company part of the PCI-SIG committee, if you have access to the specifications and standards, then you should know how specific and meticulous these documents are. I recommend you also refer to documents for mechanical and EMI specifications for hotplug. Refer to the specifications for your other questions. Trust me, we have thought of just about every application.